# IOS Build fails with annotations

Tags: ios, annotations, codenameone

My IOS builds fail if i´m using a custom annotation (very simple one) with the following message:

```
Error while working with the class: java/lang/annotation/Annotation file:com_we4it_aveedo_TestAnno no class definition
```

and a snipped from the build log for the annotation class:

```
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build5199219966381817658xxx/dist/MyApplication-src/com_we4it_aveedo_TestAnno.m:2:73: error: use of undeclared identifier 'class__java_lang_annotation_Annotation'; did you mean 'class__java_lang_InstantiationException'?
const struct clazz *base_interfaces_for_com_we4it_aveedo_TestAnno[] = {&class__java_lang_annotation_Annotation};
                                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                    class__java_lang_InstantiationException
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build5199219966381817658xxx/dist/MyApplication-src/com_we4it_aveedo_TestAnno.m:1:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build5199219966381817658xxx/dist/MyApplication-src/MyApplication-Prefix.pch:20:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build5199219966381817658xxx/dist/MyApplication-src/java_lang_Class.h:8:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build5199219966381817658xxx/dist/MyApplication-src/java_lang_InstantiationException.h:7:21: note: 'class__java_lang_InstantiationException' declared here
extern struct clazz class__java_lang_InstantiationException;
```

Annotation code:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface TestAnno
{
    public String kuchen();
}
```

Using this in my application with following code is enough to break the build.

```
Class forName = Class.forName("justForTest");
TestAnno classNameAnnotation = (TestAnno) forName.getAnnotation(TestAnno.class);
```

The problem is the second line which causes the error.
Another approach, which also failed, was following code:

```
Class forName = Class.forName("justForTest");
Annotation[] annotation = forName.getAnnotations();
for (Annotation a : annotation)
{
    if (a instanceof TestAnno)
    {
        TestAnno testAnno = (TestAnno) a;

    }
}
```

Getting all annotations works fine, but casting it to my explicit annotation breaks the build there.

Is there another approach to work with annotations or is it a bug or isnt it even supported for IOS?

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't support reflection supporting runtime annotations doesn't make as much sense see: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html

Since mobile apps are static and compiled ahead of time this isn't really necessary and won't save you anything.

Comment: I know, CN1 dont support reflection. Thats why many methods are not available. But some methods like Class.forName or getAnnotations are available. Why leave those methods in the SDK if they are not implemented and throws errors? Class.forName will work for sure (if you use the obfuscated name on android). And just because mobile apps are static and compiled doesn't mean annotations are useless. It depends on what you are using them. In our case we use them for exception handling and providing additional informations

Comment: How do you know the obfuscated name of a class? The main reason we added these methods is to allow the Java 5 code to compile, I do agree that it's a problem if it's in the API but fails for a specific target although I'm not sure if the right solution is to add them as methods map very differently on iOS.

Comment: We use the stacktrace from the exceptions which has the obfuscated name and use this to load the class.
I understand that some stuff is very complex to port to ios and may not be viable. But if its not implemented, it should be easier to know whats wrong. ( Better messages on build servers or at least javadoc for such methods )
It took us some hours to enclose this problem. Especially with the build times these days for IOS.
We managed to get around this problem by now, cause we only need these annotations for android

Comment: I agree we need to solve both faster builds and easier debugging. We plan to introduce on-device-debugging in early 2017 although we haven't announced it yet and don't have a solid schedule. It should resolve both issues.